# How can I run a DDL script over and over without error

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I need to create a DDL script for school and have it be able to run over and over. To run over and over, I need to drop everything and then run the scripts to recreate and populate my tables, including creating views, triggers, and sequences. How can I do this? I am thinking of adding this, but that seems like a lot for the scipt and not the intention of the assignment. Is there another way to do it or do I need to create a procedure like below for all objects?

This one is for a sequence, which runs fine. Now I'd have to do this for 15 other objects. **Also, how do I clear cnt for each block?**

```
DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM all_sequences WHERE sequence_name = 'EMPLOYEE_SEQ';
    
    IF cnt <> 0 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ';
    ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: there is no need, after running the next select cnt will have changed, but isn't one chekc for cnt enough ou can drop everything if a sequence was found

Comment: I have about 5 sequences and at least 5 tables and triggers to drop and then recreate them all again. And it has to be able to run over and over.

Comment: like i said, add a dropp after the first drop and creates after the create and run the code till christmas omes

Comment: It has to be viewed before running again.

Comment: no it will be overwritten during each select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: place the `DROP` commands in a PLSQL block and use an exception to suppress any error if the objects don't exist. Then create them normally:

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
   dbms_output.enable();
   execute immediate 'drop table test1';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ';
   -- place other DROP commands here
   dbms_output.put_line('Objects dropped');
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Objects not found');
end;
/

create table test1 (col1 number);
CREATE SEQUENCE EMPLOYEE_SEQ  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL;
```

First time execution:

```
Objects not found


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Table TEST1 created.


Sequence EMPLOYEE_SEQ created.
```

Second execution:

```
Objects dropped


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Table TEST1 created.

    
Sequence EMPLOYEE_SEQ created.
```

I tested this script using SQL*Developer. It assumes that all objects will be present; if one drop statement throws an error, any subsequent drop statements will not be run. Use this only for objects like tables or sequences that do not support `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` syntax. For views, stored procedures, types, etc., use `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax and don't worry about explicitly dropping them.